# Regex evaluates "not" and "no" as equal

Tags: c#, regex

I need to be able to match a sequence of words from a sentence and was trying to use regex but for some reason regex evaluates "not" and "no" as equal. Code is still in a mock stage but the idea is that a system throws an error and I need to see if a specific verbiage is contained with in. Here is the code.

```
        string message = "The field could not be calculated because the following field(s) have no value or have invalid values: [field1].";
        string[] sentences = message.Split(' ');

        string pattern = "have no value or have invalid values:";
        string[] pattern1 = pattern.Split(' ');

        string[] result = new string[pattern1.Length];
        int i = 0;

        foreach (string p in pattern1)
        {
            foreach (string s in sentences)
            {
                System.Console.Write("{0,24}", s);

                if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, p, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("  (match for '{0}' found)", p);
                    result[i] = s.Trim();
                    i++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }
        }

        bool isEqual = pattern1.SequenceEqual(result);
        if (isEqual)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Match Found");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Match NOT Found");
        }
```

Comment: Well, lets see your RegExp search expression....

Comment: Would you like the regex to not identify anything other than the exact string 'no'?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? I have a feeling that you don't need all that code if you're just checking if a given a string has a particular pattern in it.

Comment: The regular expression "no" matches "not" because "not" contains "no".  Maybe you want to anchor your patterns like "^no$".  Or just do a string comparison.

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] - there is way too much code and it includes non-obvious way of generating regular expression. One line with `Regex.Match(.....)` should be enough to demonstrate problem.

Comment: First off, thanks for your posts. I thought I was clear in stating what the issue was. I have an error message that contains certain sequence of words. I want to compare that message against a pattern of words. The approach I used was to break the message and pattern into arrays and using Regex.Match to filter out the pattern. This is how "I" know how to do it, and from all your post it appears it is inferior and you slamming me instead of offering guidance.

Comment: The issue is stated, but there are no examples of the data where it works or fails. You want people to help so you should try and help them to help you by providing the extra information they request and removing irrelevant code. Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

The regex pattern your code is using in this case is `no` (from `pattern1`, which you got by splitting `have no value or have invalid values:`)

Well `not` is certainly a match on the regex pattern `no` - because `not` *starts with* `no`.

If you wanted to be more specific you could introduce the [word boundary `\b`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
//other code

foreach (string p in pattern1)
{
    foreach (string s in sentences)
    {            
        //wrap your pattern in word boundaries
        string pat = "\b" + p + "\b"

        //use the new wrapped pattern
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(s, pat, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("  (match for '{0}' found)", pat);
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "no. Just no?" ;) - escaping regex is hard.